# How delete popup menu de copy /save in ggraphics gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

I'm make GUI with a pop up menu with right click, over a graphic but at the same time appear a pop up menu with the options copy or save graphics, how i can delete this last pop up menu?

```
 library(cairoDevice)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(gWidgets)
 library(gWidgetsRGtk2)
 require(RGtk2)

  plot1<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+ geom_point(colour = "black", size = 3)
  plot2<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+geom_point(colour = "red", size = 3)
  plot3<- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+ geom_point(colour = "yellow", size = 3,shape=20)

  options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")
  w        <-gwindow("GUI")
  g        <-ggroup(cont=w)
 graphic1 <- ggraphics(cont=g)
 print(plot1)

 ml<-list()
 ml$plot2<- list(handler=function(h,...){
  svalue(graphic1)<- print(plot2)
  })
 ml$plot3<- list(handler=function(h,...){
 svalue(graphic1)<-print(plot3)
 })

 add3rdMousePopupmenu(obj=graphic1,menulist=ml,action=graphic1)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some hidden arguments for ggraphics under RGtk2. Try passing `no_popup=TRUE` to the ggraphics constructor. If you want to remove rubber banding, the argument to pass is `do.rubber.banding=FALSE` (why . for one, _ for the other? don't ask...)

Comment: Thanks so much, i was looking and found that also `blockHandler(graphic_1)` works

Comment: That will do it too, though with a much blunter tool

Comment: Hi, i am testing with your new package _gWidgets2_ but the arguments: _no_popup_ and _do.rubber.banding_ in _ggraphics_ not work

Comment: The rubber band code is added by default (with no means to remove) and `no_popup=FALSE` should work as a hidden argument (https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2RGtk2/blob/master/R/ggraphics.R#L47).

Comment: Are you on master? It just worked for me with `ggraphics(cont=gwindow(), no_popup=TRUE)`.

Comment: i am using R 3.1 and gWidgets2 and in my pc not works, will I require some additional package?

Comment: I likely need to push a change from GitHub to CRAN. It is a bit overdue. I'll try to do so soon.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!, `no_popup` works with GitHub Version (Master) but no works with CRAN Version

Answer (score 0):

Look,

```
w <- gwindow("notebook example")
nb <- gnotebook(cont=w)

devs <- lapply(1:5, function(i) ggraphics(cont=nb,no_popup=T, label=as.character(i)))

addHandlerChanged(nb, handler=function(h,...) {
gg <- h$obj[h$pageno]
visible(gg) <- TRUE
})
```